# Spring + Hibernate don't open automatically the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing an Hibernate DAO in a Spring application using the following architecture:

I have a PersonDAO interface in which I declare the CRUD method that I want and then I create a concrete class PersonDAOImpl that implement this interface, this one:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDAOImpl2 {

    // Factory per la creazione delle sessioni di Hibernate:
        private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        // Metodo Setter per l'iniezione della dipendenza della SessionFactory:
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            System.out.println("Ho iniettato la SessionFactory: " + sessionFactory);

        }

        /** CREATE CRUD Operation:
         * Aggiunge un nuovo record rappresentato nella tabella rappresentato
         * da un oggetto Person
         */
        @Transactional(readOnly = false)
        public Integer addPerson(Person p) {

            System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");
            System.out.println("Connessione aperta: " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen());
            System.out.println("E' connesa:" + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected());

            Integer personID = personID = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(p);

            return personID;

        }

}
```

And then I have create a **MainApp** class conteining the main() method to test how it work.

The problem is that when I execute the MainApp when I try to insert a new record in the database I obtain the following error message in the stacktrace:

```
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@446adaa2] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Ho iniettato la SessionFactory: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@34a8a14b
Contesto recuperato: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@70501e4e: startup date [Sat Mar 09 10:02:37 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Creato persona1: org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person@2d35bcd7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl2$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d0c4a932 cannot be cast to org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAO
    at org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:26)
```

Seems like it don't find the Session object and now I have a doubt: I know that Spring open and close automatically the Session for every @Transactional method but it seems don't work !!!

On the contrary, if I explicitly open a new session when I call the method, it work well...in this way:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Integer addPerson(Person p) {

        System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer personID = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            personID = (Integer) session.save(p);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return personID;

    }
```

But I think that I can say Spring to automatically open the Session when enter in the method and close it when exit

This is my XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringTestDb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="MY_DB_PSWD" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="personDAOImpl" class="org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl2" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Register @Autowired annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: how is `PersonDAOImpl2` used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either use interfaces for your DAO or reconfigure the [proxy mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html) to use classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell to Spring when to "open" the session. 
There is ready for use Spring implementation which opens session before proccesing the request.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```